# no function definition: RETURN

Tags: function, return, autolisp

I want to use keyword "return" to return value for a function but I got a runtime error
[image]

I can only successfully return value as below. However, the function will not "end directly" after if condition == true at line #3.
Could someone give a hint how to use "return" keyword correctly?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoLISP does not have a `return` function.

You would need to structure your code such that the remainder of the code is evaluated as part of the `else` argument for the `if` statement, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun findLastDigitIndex ( str startIdx / char )
    (setq char (substr str startIdx 1))
    (if (or (< (ascii char) 48) (> (ascii char) 57))
        nil
        (progn
            ;; do stuff
        )
    )
)
```

But I might write the function as follows:

```lisp
(defun findLastDigitIndex ( str startIdx / dif )
    (setq str (substr str startIdx)
          dif (- (strlen str) (length (vl-member-if-not '(lambda ( a ) (< 47 a 58)) (vl-string->list str))))
    )
    (if (< 0 dif) (+ startIdx dif -1))
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I dont know how to put a code in the comment. So I post another question by putting a answer. May you take a look if my understanding is correct?

Comment: @WuYuanChun You're most welcome - please mark my answer as the solution if it adequately answers your question, so that others can see that the question has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I don't know I could do that. Already accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

It's a good convention to always put "return value" in the very end of function. In fact, it's a requirement.

Indeed in the code below, that first return value of `nil` will be overwritten by the logic that follows after it.

```lisp
(defun test()
   (if someSimpleCheck
      nil
   )
   ;; do many logic and get retValue
   retValue
)
```

In Autolisp, we cannot leave a function in the middle. It will always run its course through all of the code. So it must instead be

```lisp
(defun test()
   (if someSimpleCheck
      nil                     ; EITHER this
      (progn
         ;; do many logic and get retValue
         retValue             ; OR this
      )))
```

Here `nil` will be returned is `someSimpleCheck` is not `nil`, and `retValue` will be returned if `someSimpleCheck` is indeed `nil`.

Comment: Yes, your understanding looks to be correct. For completeness, you can force code to cease evaluation using (quit) or (exit), but these functions will result in an error being thrown, which then needs to be caught appropriately - such solutions are not quite as clean.

Comment: Thanks for Mac's reply. And Nill's help to edit my question to be a confrimed answer